# How to get a certain element in a list, given the position?

Tags: c++, list, stl

So I've got a list:

```
list<Object> myList;
myList.push_back(Object myObject);
```

I'm not sure but I'm confident that this would be the "0th" element in the array.
Is there any function I can use that will return "myObject"?

```
Object copy = myList.find_element(0);
```

?

Comment: There is no array -- it's a list.  If you want to index by integer, why don't you use `vector` instead?

Comment: If you always want element 0, use `front()`.

Comment: I have not tested this, but I would assume myList.front() + num would work here

Comment: @SergueiFedorov: no, it doesn't

Answer (score 145):

If you frequently need to access the Nth element of a sequence, `std::list`, which is implemented as a doubly linked list, is probably not the right choice.  `std::vector` or `std::deque` would likely be better.

That said, you can get an iterator to the Nth element using `std::advance`:

```
std::list<Object> l;
// add elements to list 'l'...

unsigned N = /* index of the element you want to retrieve */;
if (l.size() > N)
{
    std::list<Object>::iterator it = l.begin();
    std::advance(it, N);
    // 'it' points to the element at index 'N'
}
```

For a container that doesn't provide random access, like `std::list`, `std::advance` calls `operator++` on the iterator `N` times.  Alternatively, if your Standard Library implementation provides it, you may call `std::next`:

```
if (l.size() > N)
{
    std::list<Object>::iterator it = std::next(l.begin(), N);
}
```

`std::next` is effectively wraps a call to `std::advance`, making it easier to advance an iterator `N` times with fewer lines of code and fewer mutable variables.  `std::next` was added in C++11.

Comment: While you pay a performance penalty searching a linked list due to the lack of random access, you pay a much bigger performance penalty if you need to insert or remove data in the middle of a vector or deque. The question doesn't actually contain enough information to decide if they are using the ideal container for their purposes.

Comment: It's worth noting that when using `std::advance` or `std::next`, it is easy to invoke UB. There is no bounds checking.

Answer (score 40):

`std::list` doesn't provide any function to get element given an index. You may try to get it by writing some code, which I wouldn't recommend, because that would be inefficient if you frequently need to do so.

What you need is : `std::vector`. Use it as:

```
std::vector<Object> objects;
objects.push_back(myObject);

Object const & x = objects[0];    //index isn't checked
Object const & y = objects.at(0); //index is checked
```

Answer (score 9):

```
std::list<Object> l; 
std::list<Object>::iterator ptr;
int i;

for( i = 0 , ptr = l.begin() ; i < N && ptr != l.end() ; i++ , ptr++ );

if( ptr == l.end() ) {
    // list too short  
} else {
    // 'ptr' points to N-th element of list
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the most efficient way.  But you could convert the list into a vector.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

list<Object> myList;

vector<Object> myVector(myList.begin(), myList.end());
```

Then access the vector using the [x] operator.

```
auto x = MyVector[0];
```

You could put that in a helper function:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template<class T>
shared_ptr<vector<T>> 
ListToVector(list<T> List) {
shared_ptr<vector<T>> Vector {
        new vector<string>(List.begin(), List.end()) }
return Vector;
}
```

Then use the helper funciton like this:

```
auto MyVector = ListToVector(Object);
auto x = MyVector[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but if you must use a list, you can deference the iterator

```
*myList.begin()+N
```

Comment: +N only works for random access iterators.