# c++ list random access

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, random-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a certain element in a list, given the position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733842/how-to-get-a-certain-element-in-a-list-given-the-position)

so in python you can get an element in a list in a random access fashion....

```
list = [1,12,3]

print(list[1])
```

and it prints 12....

can you do the same thing with c++ list?

I'm talking about this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/list/

Comment: Are you talking about arrays or linked-lists? Note that `O(1)` random access is impossible with linked-lists. The best you can do with random access on linked lists is `O(n)`.

Comment: Yea, could you be more specific about what you mean by list?

Comment: Who says Python lists are C++ lists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++, the nearest along to what you want would be a vector:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(12);
v.push_back(3);
std::cout << v[1] << std::endl; // prints 12
```

You can use the iterators provided to traverse the vector, too. But once you modify the vector (insert or erase), it becomes invalid.

The actual List class provided (which is a doubly-linked list), doesn't provide this sort of feature.

Comment: Yes, in terms of implementation C++ vector is most similar to Python list.

Comment: This answer is good, but I would actually recommend `std::deque` if the usual usage is like a list but with random access.

Answer (score 3):

no. if you use std::list you have to iterate through the list to find a specific element, because list is a double-linked list, elements cannot be accessed with random access operator.
and that's because with lists, it's fast and efficient to insert or delete at any point in the list, thus what was the first element at the beginning could be the third element after modifying the list.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you're asking about arrays

int list[3(size)] = {1,12,3};

cout << list[1];

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a C++ STL list, no, that is the primary problem with the list.