# C++ std::<list> SIZE_T type

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting the process memory usage with GetProcessMemoryInfo and PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS and i want to compare who have the biggest usage.

I'm trying to use `std::<list>` to do it creating mine `<list>` with `SIZE_T` type.

I add the elements like this:

```
    list<SIZE_T> sizes;

    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info = { 0 };
    info.cb = sizeof(info);
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(process, &info, sizeof(info));

    sizes.push_back(info.WorkingSetSize);
```

And to find the biggest:

```
SIZE_T temp = 0;
for (SIZE_T i = 0; i < sizes.size(); ++i){

    if (sizes[i] > temp){
        temp = sizes[i];
    }
}
```

or am i using it wrong?

Ty
* here don't say that i can't do a SIZE_T ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/ )

Comment: Do you get a compiler error, or what question do you have? And do you really have a `std::<list>` ? (Ok, now the real definition is added, forget the last part)

Comment: What is `SIZE_T` ? Do you mean `size_t` ?

Comment: Error 1 error C2676: binary '[' : 'std::list<SIZE_T,std::allocator<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator. I'm using SIZE_T because here says that WorkingSetSize is SIZE_T http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Júlio Well, it´s true. It´s not an array etc., there is no [] implemented. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733842/how-to-get-a-certain-element-in-a-list-given-the-position if you really want to keep the list.

Comment: Maybe you want a `vector` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use array-style indexing on a `std::list`. Either change your container to a `std::vector<SIZE_T>` or change your loop, perhaps using the `std::max_element` standard library algorithm. For example:

```
SIZE_T largest = *std::max_element(sizes.begin(), sizes.end()); // assumes the list isn't empty
```

Note that `std::max_element` returns an **iterator** so I must dereference it to get the value.

Answer (score 4):

A list cannot be accessed with an index like `std::vector` because reaching the Nth element would need N operations.

What you want is just the max value, so this line is enough :

```
SIZE_T max = *std::max_element(begin(sizes),end(sizes));
```

You need to include the `algorithm` header and always try to use algorithm function against raw loop.

EDIT : `sizes` must contain something or deference with `*` is illegal

Comment: Ty! but i can't accept all. The site only allow accept 1.