# std::list remove element by index

Tags: c++, list, c++11, indexing, std

I have a std::list full of objects. Whenever I add a object, I want to store that objects index in the list, so later on I can remove it from the list.

What I want to do in pseudo code

```
myList.pushBack(element);
int index = myList.getIndexOfLastElement();

myList.erase(index);
```

For performance reasons I can't search by value.

**To clarify:**
I have element a(index 0), b(index 1), c(index 2), d(index 3)

If I delete element b, I still want to be able to access c by 2.

Comment: Is map as fast if I want to iterate through the whole map/list? I need to do that a lot.

Comment: When you iterate your list, does order of iteration matter?

Comment: I did not get you .. you want two lists. one for objects and one fo indices ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Order doesn't matter.

Comment: If order doesn't matter then why not use a set type and remove by value?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I have an object Chunk, that CAN have an object Terrain associated with it. Because theres a lot of Chunks that doesn't have a Terrain, I need a separate list for performance. A Terrain won't work without a Chunk, therefore I need to remove Terrain from the list when I remove it's Chunk. I want to store the index of the Terrain in the Chunk object.

Comment: `std::list` doesn't really have indices wither. Why are you using that data structure?

Comment: @KaareZ: `std::list::erase` takes an __iterator__ not an index. You can get an iterator by doing `std::next(myList.begin(), index)` but that takes linear time.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Is an iterator permanent to the element?

Comment: @MarcGlisse That's exactly the problem. I need to access it by the index it had when it was added, aka permanent.

Comment: That index is 2, why did you write 3??? And then let me paste the link again: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list (second paragraph).

Comment: Oh sorry. That was an error. Fixed

Comment: I repeat. `std::list` doesn't have indices. So you can't access an element by index. Talking of indices here makes no sense. If you need access by index, use a data structure that supports that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest using `std::list::iterator` instead of integer indices. `std::list::erase()` does not invalidate iterators.

```
auto index = myList.insert(myList.end(), element);

myList.erase(index);
```

Comment: Highly agree.  This is exactly what `iterator`s are there for.  `list` is specified such that iterators remain valid until the corresponding element is deleted.  `rbegin()` points at the last position pushed_back to.

Comment: What is `element` here exactly supposed to be? An integer? A pointer to the element? Do I need to point to the element, since I only want to use an index (As OP asked)? Please, if you make an example, make it a full example.

Comment: @wEight The `element` here is supposed to be exactly the `element` from the OP's question.

Comment: @Joker_vD Ah, in that case, the title is a bit misleading then. Too bad this thread is too old...

Comment: What if I want to delete the item at an arbitrary index. In the question above, it happened to be the last one, but say, my list has 10,000 elements in it, and I want to delete the 4,539th item. What should I do, move the iterator 4,539 times in a loop?

Comment: @DamnVegetables Yes, precisely, it's a list, not a vector. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733842/how-to-get-a-certain-element-in-a-list-given-the-position