# Is there any method in c++ to get an element in a list with random access?

Tags: c++, list, methods

I searched a lot but I didn't find any method like "get" in java used in lists. My problem is the following:

I have a for inside a for and I need to compare the element "i" of the list, like in java but in c++

example

```
for(int i = 0; i< x; i++){
   if(list.get(i) == NULL)
}
```

Comment: A java List is the same as std::vector.  Do not use std::list.

Comment: Can you share some more context? What type is `list`?

Comment: "do not use std:list" in this case only you mean, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a certain element in a list, given the position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733842/how-to-get-a-certain-element-in-a-list-given-the-position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists *don't* have random-access, so no. `std::list` is a linked list.

Use something that *does* have random-access, like a `std::vector`.

Also, I recommend forgetting everything you know about Java when writing in C++.
They are different languages: knowledge from one cannot generally be applied to the other.

Answer (score 0):

std::list is a linked list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

You cannot access its elements by index, since it requires traversing the list with O(n) and can be easily abused resulting in slow code.
The only way is explicitly using iterators.

Answer (score 0):

`std::list` isn't "indexable" in STL (C++).  Try a `vector` instead.

Comment: The namespace `std` is reserved for use by the C++ Standard Library. The STL is a [historical] third-party library.